# How can I use an external lib in a BEGIN block

Tags: perl

I want to use an external library in the `BEGIN` block of a Perl script.
The first test which I did was to check whether my `@INC` is getting popullated if I push some values:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    push @INC, "d:/external_pm/";

    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper @INC;
}
```

Which works as expected and shows:

```
$VAR1 = 'D:/perl/5163/site/lib';
$VAR2 = 'D:/perl/5163/lib';
$VAR3 = '.';  # I am not sure about this one?!
$VAR4 = 'd:/external_pm/';
```

Now I want to import a module right after the `push`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    push @INC, "d:/external_pm/";

    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper @INC;
    use ExtScript;
}
```

The error which follows is showing me that `@INC` was not updated:
`Can't locate ExtScript.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/perl/5163/site/lib
D:/perl/5163/lib .) at file.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at file.pl line 9.`

Why the `@INC` it's not updating?
I can't import a module in the `BEGIN` block? Or is a missusage of Perl?

Comment: should it not be `use external_pm;` Your pm files and directories should Match your module names.

Comment: Where is located your external module? Let's say that it is under lib/ExtScript.pm, you can run your main script like: perl -Ilib main.pl

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It's just a folder with scripts so the folder name won't match the sript name.

Comment: @mabe02 The path is  `D:/external_pm/ExtScript.pm`. That's why I push the directory `D:/external_pm` and try to use the `ExtScript.pm`

Comment: then you could just do `use external_pm::ExtScript;`

Comment: Tip: If `d:/external_pm/` has modules you want to make accessible to all your scripts, I would set env var PERL5LIB in this case. (Right-click on my computer | Properties | Advanced | Environment Variables)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the suggestion, I was looking at this possibility too, but the code snippet is part of a bigger application that will be deployed on different PC's and the external modules will be copied by convention in `external_pm` ( that's just a generic name to make the question more understandable), so I won't be able to change de environment before execution. I went with `require` finally.

Comment: Might make more sense to deploy it in the same dir as the script (`use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;`) or a subdir (`use FindBin qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/lib";`)

Comment: @ikegami makes a lot of sense for me too, but apparently not for the guys that developed the application, I can't change the location at this moment (it's a 50k lines+ application). I will keep in mind this convention when I will have the possibility to implement it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`use` statements are executed at compile time (specifically, during the BEGIN phase), whereas normal code is run later. Let's look at this simplified snippet:

```
BEGIN {
  push @INC, "some/dir";
  use Example;
}
```

If we spell out all phases explicitly, that would be equivalent to:

```
BEGIN {
  push @INC, "some/dir";
  BEGIN { require Example; Example->import() }
}
```

So the `Example` module will be imported before the `push` runs.

There are a number of ways to address this.

The simplest way is to put *only* the `@INC` manipulation into a BEGIN block, and import the module outside:

```
BEGIN { push @INC, "some/dir" }
use Example;
```

A better solution is to use the `lib` pragma to handle `@INC`:

```
use lib "some/dir";
use Example;
```

However, there is a major difference: `use lib` puts additional directories at the beginning of the module search path, so you may accidentally override other modules. `push @INC` only adds directories to the end, as a fallback if a module wasn't found in other locations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

`use ExtScript;` is executed before `push @INC`. Either

- move `use ExtScript;` out of the `BEGIN` block
- or change it to `require`/`import`
- or use the `-I` command-line option or `PERL5LIB` env variable.